# Image wrap on div only works if the number of lines >1

Tags: html, css

This is a weird question I know but I am having a time solving it. I have an image with `float: left;`attribute however this stying only works if the div has more than one line. When the div has 1 line it overlaps with the image. What might be the problem?

```
<div style="
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 600px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
    font-family: Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
">
    <img src="images/monkey.jpg" style="
        margin-right: 7px;
        border: 1px solid #C0C0C0;
        padding: 5px;
        float: left;
        height: 62px;
        width: 80px;
    ">
    <div style="
        margin-top: -15px;
        margin-bottom: -15px;
        word-wrap: break-word;
    ">
        <p>
            What's your plan about short posts and such?
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not sure which DIV overlap what!? Your question is not clear: what do you need to achieve?

Comment: Thanks for comment. What I'm trying to say is that when the div with margin-top:-15px property has **one** line inside. The text is shown **on** the image. However when it has more than one line div is properly shifted to right side.

Comment: the easiest way would be to add a `float:left` to the div that encapsulate the text

Comment: Ok, I see that in Firefox 11 I have something different than on Chrome 18 (I am on Ubuntu)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what works on both Firefox 11 and Chrome 18:

```
<div style="overflow:hidden;width:600px;border:1px solid black;padding:5px;font-family:Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:14px;">
    <img src="images/monkey.jpg" style="float:left;margin-right:7px;border:1px solid #C0C0C0;padding:5px;height:62px;width:80px;">
    <div style="float:left;margin-bottom:-15px;word-wrap:break-word;">
        <p>What's your plan about short posts and such?</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Buq2T/1/) to play with in other browsers.